# How to show success message below html form after form submit which is being handled by different php file

Tags: javascript, php, forms

There is a form in my `index.php` file. This form is handling from a different php file named `send-mail.php`. I want to show a message inside `alert` div in `index.php` file. Can this be done by php or javascript will be needed too?

index.php:

```
<section id="contact">
<form action="send-mail.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">
   <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="your name" type="text" required>
   <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="your e-mail" type="email" required>
   <textarea cols="50" id="message" name="message" placeholder="your enquiry" rows="4" required></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>
<div class="alert alert-dismissible fade in hide" role=alert>
   <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=alert aria-label=Close><span aria-hidden=true>&times;</span></button>
</div>
</section>
```

send-mail.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get the submitted form data
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Recipient email
    $toEmail = 'user@example.com';

    $emailSubject = 'Contact Request Submitted by '.$name;
    $htmlContent = '<h2>Contact Request Submitted</h2>
        <h4>Name</h4><p>'.$name.'</p>
        <h4>Email</h4><p>'.$email.'</p>
        <h4>Message</h4><p>'.$message.'</p>';

    // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: '.$name.'<'.$email.'>'. "\r\n";

    // Send email
    if(mail($toEmail,$emailSubject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
        $statusMsg = 'Your contact request has been submitted successfully !';
        $msgClass = 'alert-success';
        header('location: index.php#contact');
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Your contact request submission failed, please try again.';
        $msgClass = 'alert-danger';
        header('location: index.php#contact');
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: You can send the `$statusMsg` as a query variable to `index.php` and use it if it exists.

Comment: You already have everything you need: `header('location: index.php?sentmail=success#contact');` Now refer to `$_GET['sentmail']` in index.php to display content accordingly.

Comment: pass . some flag in your redirected link .based on that flag show some success messege in that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your redirects to:

```
header('location: index.php?result='.$msgClass.'#contact');
```

Then adding the following to your index.php file:

```
if ($_GET['result']=="alert-success") {
    // display success message here
} elseif ($_GET['result']=="alert-danger") {
    // display error message here
}
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear :)